# dropzoneJS - preview image in another element outside dropzone class

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter, i've been searching for this part and no answer is what i want.
how to add preview image and file in another element of dropdownJS, let's call div#preview like this

```
<form action='upload' class='dropzone'>
    //dropzone usually add preview in here
</form>

<div id='preview'>
    //what i want image preview in here, so form is just for uploading
</div>
```

My goal is:
1. Preview image is in outside dropzone class
2. After refresh page, still displaying preview image
3. For displaying after refresh page, is it possible without saving filename in database?

Comment: You might want to share what you have tried so far :)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry my fault didn't read dropzonejs doc detailed, 
The solution is just add setting

```
previewsContainer: //set to where element to display,
```

example :

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
    url: " some_upload_url ",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    previewsContainer: '#preview', //this will change preview to element selected
    etc etc
```

Comment: previewsContainer NOT previewContainer